# Assign internal IP address based on subdomain

Tags: networking, nat, internal-dns

I have a domain name, let's say foo.com. I have a server which has a public IP (Server-A). I also have a lot of servers (Server-B, Server-C, Server-D etc) which are all connected in a private network along with Server-A. Server-B,C,D do not have a public IP but they have their internal private IPs. Obviously I can't access Server-B,C,D from the internet.

I want a setup wherein foo.com should point to Server-A but I should be able to access the internal servers by using a subdomain. So b.intern.foo.com should point to Server-B, c.intern.foo.com should point to Server-C, d.intern.foo.com should point to Server-C and so on.

What I mean by 'point to' is that b.intern.foo.com should allow me to access all ports of Server-B and not just HTTP port(otherwise I would just use Nginx). That means that if I ssh on b.intern.foo.com, I should get to the SSH server running on Server-B. If I open up b.intern.foo.com on my browser, it should hit the Nginx running on Server-B and so on. Basically all the ports of Server-B should be accessible by b.intern.foo.com from the Internet.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for an entirely protocol-independent proxy that has something like HTTP host headers, which (AFAIK) doesn't exist.

The only other thing that looks like this is a NAT/PAT solution which will require as many public IP addresses as simply using public IP addresses in the first place.

Comment: Can't I just use something like NAT on server-A which can route the requests based on subdomain? I think I'm getting what you're saying is that not all protocol may have a HTTP's HOST like headers to even be able to differentiate between the two requests.

Comment: No, NAT is IP. It doesn't know DNS names.

Comment: Also, almost all your client applications don't know host name either. Once they've made the DNS lookup, they're connecting to an IP address. That's why http has host headers in the first place, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want with a single public IP address. When outside your network, even if you make the DNS return the private IP address of an internal node then the public internet will not route it for you. If you make the internal nodes external IP address the same as Server-A then server A will think the packets are for it.